# Add an item to list in host web, from an app part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin

Currently my app reads the list items and shows in an app part(visible to all site visitors). Now we would like to extent the functionality. 
If the user has **contribute permission** to the list(site), there should be a link in the app part where they can click to add a new list item. How may I achieve it? and what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XsltListViewWebPart` which provide more OOTB look and feel while adding to the list. Provide the `ListUrl` property with the list you want to add items to

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="full" Title="loc:full">
        <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server"
            ListUrl="Lists/CustomDocumentLibrary"
            IsIncluded="True"
            JsLink="clientTemplate.js"
            NoDefaultStyle="TRUE"
            PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW"
            Default="False"
            ViewContentTypeId="0x">
        </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
    </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Comment: Thanks Falak for your quick reponse: as I'm a novice, and would like to know, how can I add `XsltListViewWebPart` in an app. I know you might not have time to explain everything, but could you please point me to a sample-app/tutorial or any other related information.

Comment: You could add this in Default.aspx of your App

Comment: When i take list from HostUrl, how do I get the value `ListUrl`? Googled it and found examples of list in the appweb, but not host. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can ListUrl for AppWeb as well as Host web. See some examples at Chris o Brien's blog: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/08/working-with-web-parts-within.html

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to acheive adding new list item to ShareLoint list using Javascript in APP 2013.

Write the following code in your App.js and call "btnSubmit_CreateListItem" event in ADD button click:

```
function btnSubmit_CreateListItem() {

    //siteUrl will be your host web url.

    //app web
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //host web
    var parentCtx = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, siteUrl);
    var oList = parentCtx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)

    );
}


function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: what is `siteUrl` in this case? it seems that this value has never been set...